# Compile dynamicaly linkable libraries

Tags: windows, dll, cmake

I'm currently trying to compile dynamicaly linkable libraries, which would link during run-time with an application I'm writing.
I'm not sure how these libraries are called, so just to be sure : they're those libraries you load not during compilation, but during runtime using :
- dlopen / dlsync using libdl
- LoadLibrary / (another one with a complicated name) using Windows.

The thing is I can't find a CMake-way to compile those librairies under Windows : using Linux, this works perfectly :

```
set(libName  myLib)
set(srcFiles myLib.cpp)

add_library(${libName} MODULE ${srcFiles})
```

Still, running Windows, it doesn't work at all : the Makefile is trying to link some pieces of code the myLib.cpp is referencing to (but it shouldn't... those symbols should be resolved at runtime).

I'm using the CodeBlocks MinGW generator if it may helps.

Comment: The code that you've provided here should build a dll just fine. What compiler or linker errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help:

add_library(${libname} SHARED ${srcfiles})

As CMake documentation says, MODULE should be used for building libraries that should be dynamically loaded using *dlopen*-like functionality. On Windows use SHARED instead of MODULE.

Comment: Same results, unfortunatly =/ !